# Where is Outlook's save FileDialog?

Tags: outlook, office-2007, outlook-2007, outlook-addin

I'm working on an Outlook add-in that requires the Office specific FileDialog to interoperate with a Sharepoint site; the common file dialog doesn't have the interoperability. I know that both Word and Excel have a get_fileDialog method under Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Application, but Outlook doesn't seem to. How do I launch an Outlook FileDialog? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Microsoft Common Dialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa155724%28office.10%29.aspx)

If you have COMDLG32.OCX ("Common Dialog ActiveX Control") installed, then you can use this - it's explained here, with an example. (Scroll down just past the screenshot entitled "FIGURE 2: Don't try to select more than one file in Word! ").

Answer (score 1):

It appears that Outlook's Application object does not offer `FileDialog`. But a simple workaround, if you are willing to have an Excel reference, is:

```
Dim fd As FileDialog
Set fd = Excel.Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
Dim folder As Variant    
If fd.Show = -1 Then
    For Each folder In fd.SelectedItems
        Debug.Print "Folder:" & folder & "."
    Next
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

```
'Add a "Module". Then add the declarations like this to it.

Option Explicit
Private Declare Function GetOpenFileName _
                Lib "comdlg32.dll" _
                Alias "GetOpenFileNameA" (pOpenfilename As OPENFILENAME) As Long
Private Type OPENFILENAME
    lStructSize As Long
    hwndOwner As Long
    hInstance As Long
    lpstrFilter As String
    lpstrCustomFilter As String
    nMaxCustFilter As Long
    nFilterIndex As Long
    lpstrFile As String
    nMaxFile As Long
    lpstrFileTitle As String
    nMaxFileTitle As Long
    lpstrInitialDir As String
    lpstrTitle As String
    flags As Long
    nFileOffset As Integer
    nFileExtension As Integer
    lpstrDefExt As String
    lCustData As Long
    lpfnHook As Long
    lpTemplateName As String
End Type

Public Function MyOpenFiledialog() As String
    Dim OFName As OPENFILENAME
    OFName.lStructSize = Len(OFName)
    'Set the parent window
    OFName.hwndOwner = Application.hWnd
    'Set the application's instance
    OFName.hInstance = Application.hInstance
    'Select a filter
    OFName.lpstrFilter = "Text Files (*.txt)" + Chr$(0) + "*.txt" + Chr$(0) + "All Files (*.*)" + Chr$(0) + "*.*" + Chr$(0)
    'create a buffer for the file
    OFName.lpstrFile = Space$(254)
    'set the maximum length of a returned file
    OFName.nMaxFile = 255
    'Create a buffer for the file title
    OFName.lpstrFileTitle = Space$(254)
    'Set the maximum length of a returned file title
    OFName.nMaxFileTitle = 255
    'Set the initial directory
    OFName.lpstrInitialDir = "C:\"
    'Set the title
    OFName.lpstrTitle = "Open File - VB Forums.com"
    'No flags
    OFName.flags = 0
    'Show the 'Open File'-dialog
    If GetOpenFileName(OFName) Then
        MsgBox "File to Open: " + Trim$(OFName.lpstrFile)
        MyOpenFiledialog = Trim$(OFName.lpstrFile)
    Else
        MsgBox "Cancel was pressed"
        MyOpenFiledialog = vbNullString
    End If
End Sub 'Usage:
Private Sub Command1_Click()
    Text1.Text = MyOpenFiledialog
End Sub
```

Comment: Outlook does not support FileOpen dialogues off Application.
Also www.slipstick.com is the best Outlook developers site for tips and code.

Comment: I probably should have mentioned I'm using VSTO, not VBA. In any case, I dno't think makign my own dialog box would help since it needed the really specific SharePoint functionality that the Office dialog box provided.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me (Outlook 2007) ? I think there is a minor Typo in that the Function 'MyOpenFiledialog()' is terminated with an 'End Sub' - but I changed this to 'End Function' and now receive the error //Run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method// - pressing 'DEBUG' takes me to the line //OFName.hwndOwner = Application.hWnd//

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Sub TestFileDialog()
    Dim otherObject As Excel.Application
    Dim fdFolder As office.FileDialog

    Set otherObject = New Excel.Application
    otherObject.Visible = False
    Set fdFolder = otherObject.Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    fdFolder.Show
    Debug.Print fdFolder.SelectedItems(1)
    otherObject.Quit
    Set otherObject = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub multiEML2MSG()

Const PR_ICON_INDEX = &H10800003

Dim objPost As Outlook.PostItem
Dim objSafePost As Redemption.SafePostItem
Dim objNS As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim objInbox As Outlook.MAPIFolder


Set objNS = Outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set objInbox = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
Set objPost = objInbox.Items.Add(OlItemType.olPostItem)

Set objSafePost = New Redemption.SafePostItem



    Dim xlObj As Excel.Application
    Dim fd As Office.FileDialog

    Set xlObj = New Excel.Application

    Set fd = xlObj.Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    With fd
        .Title = "Select your PST File"
        .ButtonName = "Ok"
        .Show

        If fd.SelectedItems.Count <> 0 Then
            xDirect$ = fd.SelectedItems(1) & "\"
            xFname$ = Dir(xDirect$, 7)


            licznik = 1
            Do While xFname$ <> ""

            XPathEML = xDirect$ & xFname$
            XPathMSG = Replace(XPathEML, ".eml", ".msg", , , vbTextCompare)
            Debug.Print XPath, Replace(XPath, ".eml", ".msg", , , vbTextCompare)


            objPost.Save
            objSafePost.Item = objPost
            objSafePost.Import XPathEML, Redemption.RedemptionSaveAsType.olRFC822
            objSafePost.MessageClass = "IPM.Note"
            objSafePost.Fields(PR_ICON_INDEX) = none
            objSafePost.SaveAs XPathMSG, Outlook.OlSaveAsType.olMSG



            xFname$ = Dir
            licznik = licznik + 1
        Loop

        End If
    End With

    xlObj.Quit
    Set xlObj = Nothing
    Set objSafePost = Nothing
    Set objPost = Nothing
    Set objInbox = Nothing
    Set objNS = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!